# Sql Alchemy > TypeError: 'instancemethod' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, dictionary, sqlalchemy, python-2.6

Here's what I've got:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from web.models.card import *
connectionString = "postgresql://www:www@localhost/prod"
databaseEngine = create_engine(connectionString)
sessionFactory = sessionmaker(autoflush = True, autocommit = False, bind = databaseEngine)
session = sessionFactory()
CardsCollection = session.query(card).all()
_content = {}
for index in range(0, len(CardsCollection)):
    c = CardsCollection[index]
    _content[index] = c
print json.dumps(_content)
```

And here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/src/py/raspberry/src/dictionaryTest.py", line 15, in 
    CardsCollection = session.query(card).all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 1453, in all
    return list(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 1676, in instances
    rows = [process[0](row, None) for row in fetch]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 2234, in _instance
    populate_state(state, dict_, row, isnew, only_load_props)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 2113, in populate_state
    populator(state, dict_, row)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/strategies.py", line 127, in new_execute
    dict_[key] = row[col]
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object does not support item assignment
```

Can someone help me out with this?  I've tried a few things, and researched into how dictionaries work... but its just not jumping out at me.

**[edit for strange resolution]**  Apparently, overriding the `self.__dict__(self)` method on the card model is what did it.  I'm not entirely sure why, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__dict__` is a [special attribute](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#index-862) holding current state of instance, overwriting it with with method will certainly lead to troubles.